# WPF - Prevent text selection while opening DropDown

Tags: c#, wpf

In my code i open DropDown when user typed in 3+ chars. You can see how in works at this gif.
[image: Default]

As you see when I'm trying to open DropDown from code in editable ComboBox like this:

```
comboBox.IsDropDownOpen = true;
```

All the text that I typed in becomes selected. Is there a way to avoid this behaviour?

**Note**: nullify selection is not a good solution. Yep, it works, but i still can see how text is selected and after 1 moment - is not.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to try to get that TextBox from ComboBox template:

```
var textBox = (TextBox)combobox.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", combobox);
```

And then, you could do whatever you want to this `textBox`, for example, the following would remove the current selection:

```
textBox.Select(textBox.Text.Length, 0);
```

UPD:

Overriding ComboBox example (with textBox selectedtext brush change):

```
public class MyCustomComboBox : ComboBox
    {
        private int currentCaretIndex;

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();

            var child = GetTemplateChild("PART_EditableTextBox");
            if (child != null)
            {
                var textBox = (TextBox)child;
                textBox.SelectionChanged += OnDropSelectionChanged;
                textBox.TextChanged += TextBox_TextChanged;
                
            }
        }

        private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox txt = (TextBox)sender;
            if (txt.Text.Length > 2)
            {
                SolidColorBrush solidColorBrush = (SolidColorBrush)txt.SelectionBrush;
                txt.SelectionBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
                base.IsDropDownOpen = true;
                txt.SelectionBrush = solidColorBrush;
            }
        }

        private void OnDropSelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox txt = (TextBox)sender;

            if (base.IsDropDownOpen && txt.SelectionLength > 0)
            {
                txt.CaretIndex = currentCaretIndex + 1;
            }
            if (txt.SelectionLength == 0 && txt.CaretIndex != 0)
            {
                currentCaretIndex = txt.CaretIndex;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi. Did you read the "note"?
I know that i can deselect text. But i don't want to see how text is selected and then deselected in UI.

Comment: Yes, i see it now, sorry...
Then you would want to override combobox and work with OnDropSelectionChanged

Comment: I understand that solution is in overriding default comboBox. But I don't have enough experience to find out what exactly should i change.

Comment: I have just updated my example... hope it helps you

Comment: How can I know that selection was changed by code, not by user?

Comment: You've asked how to prevent the selection - i gave you now a complete example, updated my answer again.

As regards on how to determine if this is user or not  - that is already another question, different from the orignal post.

Comment: Well, what we've got in the end is not working solution based on deselecting the text (what i've asked to avoid). Anyway thx for answer.

Comment: Ok. So even this is not working, also blinking... i see then - the only possible solution for you - is to play with styles (not that easy task), or, at least, with  - brush of selection (textBox.SelectionBrush property) in that textbox of combobox.

Comment: Updated my example again. Example is just to show it works, quite primitive though...With the help of one more even - TextChanged event of a textbox, i am now changing the selection brush when it is needed, and then, getting it back to whatever it was. Compiled and tried - works fine for me. 
Hope it helps you now and you can adjust this example to your code